# How to make new data is a function of last data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, lag

In SQL server I have a table just like the following table, original, and I want to update where Index ID>3
and the principle is lastaccmulated*2 + movement.

For example
where Index ID =3     accumulated =  8 * 2 + 2 =18

I tried the `lag` function but it can only be used in select, which means I cannot finish in one update.
Is there any sharp function to make this happen?

Table orginal

| IndexID | accumulated | movement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 8 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | 0 | 2 |

Table what I want after update

| IndexID | accumulated | movement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 8 | 2 |
| 3 | 18 | 2 |
| 4 | 38 | 2 |
| 5 | 78 | 2 |

Just like above mention, it went wrong when I use lag function.

Comment: Firstly you really shouldn't store that sort of data, you should calculate it when you need it. However if you must consider using an updatable CTE i.e. calculate the new value in a CTE and then apply that using an update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #YOUR_TABLE 

SELECT
    id, 
    accumulated,
    movement
INTO #YOUR_TABLE
FROM (
    VALUES
    (1, 5, 2),
    (2, 8, 2),
    (3, 0, 2),
    (4, 0, 2),
    (5, 0, 2),
    (6, 0, 2)
) src (id, accumulated, movement)

;WITH
CALCULATION AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        2 * accumulated + movement as accumulated
    FROM #YOUR_TABLE
    WHERE id = 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        yt.id,
        2 * c.accumulated + yt.movement as accumulated
    FROM CALCULATION c
        JOIN #YOUR_TABLE yt ON yt.id = c.id + 1
)
UPDATE yt SET
    yt.accumulated = c.accumulated
FROM #YOUR_TABLE yt
    JOIN CALCULATION c ON
        c.id = yt.id
WHERE
    yt.id >= 3
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)    -- To prevent recursion limitiations

SELECT * FROM #YOUR_TABLE
```

We are using recursive CTE here. Before `UNION ALL` we give values for step zero, after we have calculation based on previous step (`yt.id = c.id + 1`).

Comment: Hi AKedzierski , thanks

Comment: i run your code, its good.
the only thing is 

WHERE
    yt.id >= 3 ( should be 2)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)